# using SharedPreferences for passing a variable from Receiver to Activity

Tags: android

I am using sharedprefs to pass a variable from receiver to activity.
It seems to be correct and if I close and restart the app I can see that the receiver has written sharedprefs and activity can read the last written value.
But while the app is running, variable does not change. It does not get the value from the receiver.

Here's my code from the receiver:

```
 if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(bundle))
        {
            final String message = bundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPref.edit().putString("scrltxt", message).apply();
                Toast.makeText(context, message , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

and this is the code from activity:

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesx = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    scrltxt = sharedPreferencesx.getString("scrltxt", "");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), scrltxt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    mEdit.setText(scrltxt);
```

so what is wrong ?
why can't the receiver write before app closes ?

Btw, I am also reading from this shared prefs file on a separate service in the same app.

Answer (score 0):

The app doesn't update because onResume method isn't called when the broadcast receives the message and this is normal. I think you're working with different classes, so you need an interface. Define an interface in the class of your broadcast:

```
public class MyTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
Sender sender;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
  if(intent.getAction()=="YourAction")
  {
  sender = (MyActivity) context;
  sender.messageReceived();
  }
}
public interface Sender
{
     void messageReceived();
}

}
```

And then implement it in your activity:

```
MyActivity extends AppCompactActivity implements Sender
{
//other methods

@Override
public void messageReceived()
{
    // set the text
}

}
```

In this way, when the broadcast receives the intent, you can update the text immediately.

Comment: actually, I make the app call OnResume by taking it foreground manually. Shouldn't that work ? Anyway, I tried your method. But that requires the activity to implement Sender. And my activity is extended from activity. "public class FrmActivity extends Activity". how can I add Sender as implements ?

Comment: @KamunaNakamuna implements MyTestReceiver.Sender. You don't have problems with implements, you can implement infinite interfaces

Comment: 11-05 00:07:53.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.FireReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.FireReceiver$Sender
11-05 00:07:53.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3369)
11-05 00:07:53.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
11-05 00:07:53.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.j

Comment: if I add the @Override above messagereceived , it says "- The method messageReceived() of type FrmActivity must override a superclass method"

Comment: @KamunaNakamuna Are you sure that you've implemented the interface in your activity?

Comment: public class FrmActivity extends Activity implements FireReceiver.Sender {

Comment: public void messageReceived()
 {
  final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferencesx = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  scrltxt = sharedPreferencesx.getString("scrltxt", "");
 }

Comment: does not accept the messagereceived method if @override is given

Comment: so what is the problem ?

Comment: @KamunaNakamuna How is it possible? If you implement the interface, you have to override that method

Comment: ok. I found the issue about "override" , it was because my eclipse used Java 1.5 . now I set it to 1.6 and @override is accepted. but the app closes with error messages I posted above " java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.FireReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.FireReceiver$Sender "

Comment: @KamunaNakamuna I've updated the answer. Now it should works

Comment: well, it did not work for me so I used another method. called activity with an intent and passed the attributes with putExtra. I am not sure if I have to accept your answer as correct. should I ?

Comment: @KamunaNakamuna  Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158271/discussion-between-curio-and-kamuna-nakamuna).